# android ffmpeg build remove the version number

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I made reference to others compile tutorial

```
configure
```

Modify the content：

```
SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR='$(SLIBNAME).$(LIBMAJOR)'

LIB_INSTALL_EXTRA_CMD='$$(RANLIB)"$(LIBDIR)/$(LIBNAME)"'

SLIB_INSTALL_NAME='$(SLIBNAME_WITH_VERSION)'

SLIB_INSTALL_LINKS='$(SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR)$(SLIBNAME)'
```

Replace：

```
SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR='$(SLIBPREF)$(FULLNAME)-$(LIBMAJOR)$(SLIBSUF)'

LIB_INSTALL_EXTRA_CMD='$$(RANLIB)"$(LIBDIR)/$(LIBNAME)"'

SLIB_INSTALL_NAME='$(SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR)'

SLIB_INSTALL_LINKS='$(SLIBNAME)'
```

build result:
libavdevice-55.so …

build_android.sh

```
NDK=/home/dennis/android-ndk-r9d
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/ 
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 
enter code here
function build_one
{
./configure \  
--prefix=$PREFIX \
--enable-shared \  
--disable-static \ 
--disable-doc \  
--disable-ffserver \ 
--enable-cross-compile \  
--cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \ 
--target-os=linux \ 
--arch=arm \ 
--sysroot=$SYSROOT \  
--extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \  
--extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \  
$ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG  
} 
CPU=arm  
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU  
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"  
build_one
```

I want to remove the version number
result:
libavdevice.so …

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate what compile tutorial you were using. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: Why would you want to change `libavdevice-55.so` to `libavdevice.so`? And maybe its will be OK with you to get `libavdevice-.so`?

Comment: javacv lib jni  using libavdevice.so now build libavdevice-55.so   jni not found , How remove the version number build

Answer (score 2):

No need to change config.mak

Just change

```
--target-os=linux
```

with

```
--target-os=android
```

My example:

```
NDK=${HOME}/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle
ABI=arm

./configure \
    --arch=$ABI \
    --target-os=android \
    --disable-everything \
    --disable-symver \
    --enable-runtime-cpudetect \
    --enable-pic \
    --enable-shared \
    --disable-static \
    --prefix=../build/$ABI \
    --cross-prefix=$NDK/toolchains/$ABI-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/$ABI-linux-androideabi- \
    --sysroot=$NDK/platforms/android-26/arch-$ABI \
    --extra-cflags="-march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -fPIC -DANDROID" \
    --extra-ldflags="" \
    || exit 1

    make clean
    make -j4 || exit 1
    make install || exit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

in `./configure`:

```
SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR='$(SLIBPREF)$(FULLNAME)$(SLIBSUF)'
```

in `./library.mak`: change line

```
$(SUBDIR)$(SLIBNAME): $(SUBDIR)$(SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR)
```

with

```
$(SUBDIR)$(SLIBNAME).qqq: $(SUBDIR)$(SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR)
```

Comment: build error      
make: Circular libavdevice/libavdevice.so <- libavdevice/libavdevice.so dependency dropped.
ln: `libavdevice.so' and `libavdevice.so' are the same file
make: *** [install-libavdevice-shared] Error 1

Comment: Luckily, it's enough to simply disable the dependency of `$(SUBDIR)$(SLIBNAME)` on `$(SUBDIR)$(SLIBNAME_WITH_MAJOR)`. See the fixed answer.

Comment: root@iZu1h8u9uovZ:/home/ffmpeg-2.6.2# make install
INSTALL libavdevice/libavdevice.so
STRIP   install-libavdevice-shared
ln: `libavdevice.so' and `libavdevice.so' are the same file
make: *** [install-libavdevice-shared] Error 1
root@iZu1h8u9uovZ:/home/ffmpeg-2.6.2#

Comment: You should not `make install` for cross-compiled libraries